# Macbook 5,2 (Mid-2009) optical bay hard drive enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, ssd, optical-drive

I was wondering what about my Mid-2009 Macbook makes optical hard drive enclosures like [this one](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/9-5-mm-PATA-Optical-Bay-SATA-Hard-Drive-Enclosure/IF107-078) incompatible with the enclosure. And if there is another way that could get a second drive in there.

Comment: at least post a model number..

Comment: The model number (A1181) is the same for 16 other MacBooks. Here is a link to the MacBook I am talking about http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.13-white-13-mid-2009-nvidia-specs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this site](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DDAMBS0GB/), it is compatible but there are some limitations:
*2008/2009 MacBook/MacBook Pro 13", 15", and 17" models. (Model IDs: MacBookPro5,1; 5,2; 5,3; 5,4; 5,5 and MacBook5,1; 6,1; 7,1) While a 6G SSD does function, it will only do so at SATA Revision 1.0 (1.5Gb/s) speeds rather that the SATA Revision 2.0 (3.0Gb/s) speed the machine can deliver. Should owners of these machines desire another SSD option, the [Mercury Electra™ 3G SSD](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/internal_storage/Mercury_Extreme_SSD_Sandforce/Solid_State_Pro/) does run at the full SATA Revision 2.0 (3Gb/s) specification.*

What this means is that your macbook does not have a connection fast enough for most ssd's and you won't be able to utilize the full potential of such a drive.
You can always contact the guys at owc and ask for a recommendation for your mac.